# How to get back the firefox apparmor profile after deleting it?

Tags: firefox, apparmor

I deleted the apparmor profile for firefox when I was tinkering with it... And now I can't get it back.

I uninstalled (complete) the apparmor program, profiles, etc. And when it reinstalled, I still don't get the profile back (ie.  `/etc/apparmor.d./usr.bin.firefox*` )

I learned that the apparmor profile for firefox is actually an apart of the firefox package... But I uninstalled firefox and reinstalled it and I still didn't get the file `usr.bin.firefox` )

Is there somewhere I can download the file manually?

Comment: Please accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Dpkg says that the `firefox` package is responsible for it:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
firefox: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
```

So, instead of reinstalling apparmor, reinstall Firefox:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install firefox
```

During the reinstallation, you'll be prompted whether you want to restore the file or not:

```
Configuration file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox'
 ==> Deleted (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** usr.bin.firefox (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

Choose `Y` to install the file again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can pick it out of the .deb package from **packages.ubuntu.com** using file-roller to extract it.